# application icon image doesn't show in taskbar in "small icon" setting

Tags: vb.net

I have a *vb.net 2008* application which has its corresponding icon.
The icon shows correctly except in the taskbar when the "small icon" setting is on.

My vb.net project includes a *.ico* file which when I see in the *IDE* includes 16x16, 32x32, 48x48, 64x64 and 256x256 bitmaps, in 4, 24 and 32 bits, also 3 .png images in 256x256 32 bits each.

I made the icon myself simply using a 64x64 bitmap and then converting it to *.ico*, and assigning it to the application in the project properties. I thought windows would use and escalate the corresponding image, it shows even in the file explorer properly in the small icon form, but not in the taskbar.

What's going on or what do I need to do? I'm not very familiar with this. Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the correct *size/bit-depth* version in your *icon file* for whatever context WinForms wanted (e.g. the form's title bar icon, the system tray icon, the taskbar
icon, or the desktop shortcut icon) to insure it will work. You have to maintain the transparency too.

Read the following [article](http://www.hhhh.org/cloister/csharp/icons/).

Comment: Thanks for the article, in effect my .ico file was missing some bitmaps versions; by the way another problem was that the icons weren't being updated in windows because a problem in the icon chache, these links could be useful to abybody with the same problem as me: 
http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/213923-46-change-icon-shortcut
http://www.windowskb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/windowsxp/160805/Missing-or-wrong-icons

Comment: @GHR: Could you please port it as an answer to make it more visible to users. And you can accept it even if it was yours